# Java: Efficient way of getting sublists from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `Person[]` array as follows

```
[A, B, C, D .....]
```

Each person in the list is friends with another in that list. So each person has a friend list associated with him/her as follows

```
Person -> Friend List

[A] -> [B, C, D]

[B] -> [A, C, D]

[C] -> [A, B, D]
```

and so on.

To achieve this, I am doing the following (all the persons are in `people[]`)

```
   ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(people));
   for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
   {
       Person p = people[i];
       for (Person p2: persons)
       {
           if (p2.name == p.name) continue;
           p.add_to_friend_list(p2);
       }
   }
```

It works fine for small datasets but obviously for large sets it takes a lot of time.

I was wondering if there is a way to speed this up or something that I am missing/doing wrong.

Update:
The friend list is different for each year. e.g. (file.txt)

```
[Year1]4
A
B
D
E
[YEAR2]4
G
H
A
D
[YEAR3]5
K
L
M
C
D
```

I am reading the data from the file.

Comment: You're basically creating a whole lot of copies of the same list, with only one difference in each: the person is not a friend of him/herself. Why not just simply share the same list, and only filter it when needed. Note that we have no idea of what you're doing with those persons and friends.

Comment: I've updated the post with some additional data. Not sure if it will help

Comment: I did not really understand your question, would you please elaborate more, especially what do you mean by `p2.name == p.name`.

Comment: @Yahya p2==p.name is check to make sure a person is not added to his own friend list. Basically a person is friends with everyone on the list and that is what I am trying to generate, efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

To get friends list of person,
just remove self from the `Person[]` array,the remain of `Person[]` array is the friend list of the person.

Comment: Do make a copy though, before removing self from the array.

Comment: Of course，We can either copying the original array before removing or copying the remain array after removing.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT 1**

I have edited the answer based on the feedback of @NickL in the comments.
This alternative is OO and it improves access to the different objects in a more direct way than an arraylist.

It enables access direct access to the person and in the person direct access to any of its frieds using a hashtable instead of going through the array item by item to find the desired person.

If there is a special need in recovering the objects in a certain order a TreeMap can be used instead of a HashMap.

The HashMap items can also be looped one by one using its keys.

```
class Person{
    String id;
    HashMap<String, Person> friends = new HashMap<>();

    public void addFriend(String id, Person friend){
       friends.put(id, friend);
    }
    ...
}

HashMap<String, Person> people = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as what OP showed in terms of time complexity, probably worse for memory, and a lot worse in terms of that it is not OO.